# Get a column of probability values for a certain class

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

When using randomforest in sklearn to do a binary classification.
I know I can use `clf.predict(X)` to get the predicted class.
And when I use `clf.predict_proba(X)`, I get an array look like this:
[image]

I think the first column indicates the probability of the prediction? 
How can I get a column that is the probability of the class being 1?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [`RandomForest.predict_proba`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba) docs:

> ```
> predict_proba(X)
> ```
>
> Predict class probabilities for X.
>
> **Returns**:
>    `p` : [...] The class probabilities of the input samples. The
>   order of the classes corresponds to that in the attribute `classes_`.

You can look at the `clf.classes_` attribute, see at what index your class `1` appears, and then just access the probabilities as so:

```
prob_class_1 = clf.predict_proba(X)[:, i]
```

Where `i` is the index of class `1` in `clf.classes_`.

Comment: Just to be sure, If I would run it without `predict_proba`, I would get all classes as 1, which have in `predict_proba(X)[:,1]` a value which is greater then `0.5`correct?

Comment: Yes, because it's binary classification. But more generally, which ever class has the largest prob gets assigned.